# Holding onExit in ui-router

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to display an animation on an element in the page as the user is leaving a state. This is what I currently have:

```
{
    .....,
    views: { ... },
    onExit: function(){
        someEle.classList.remove("someClass");   //CSS transition
    }
}
```

However, as soon as the state is being left, the view of the exiting state gets destroyed and there is no animation. Is there a way to "hold up" the exit of the state for certain amount of time until the animation is done?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Angular JS, but have you tried catching the exit event, prevent it from firing using `preventDefault()` at the beginning of your `onExit` event handler, setting a timeout for the duration of the css transition and sending the event again on completion?

Comment: @Marventus - But then how do I resume it?

Comment: I think `return true;` should do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Check out this new attempt, with click events on `<a>` tags. I am successfully preventing the event from firing for the duration of the transition, and even managing to reset the defaultPrevented property of the event and dispatch it from the `transitionend` event, but even though the event is definitely firing (because of the second transition on the link), it was still not redirecting to the link url.
However, I was able to do so by accessing the `target.href` property of the event.
Check out the code below:

### Pure JS:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
function onTransitionEnd(event) {
    window.location.href = event.target.href;
    // Uncomment line below to refire the event
    // event.target.dispatchEvent(event);
}
for(i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
    links[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        this.addEventListener("transitionend", function() {
            // Uncomment lines below to refire the event
            /* delete e.defaultPrevented;
            e.defaultPrevented = false; */
            onTransitionEnd(e);
        });
        if( this.className.search(/animate/) > -1 )
            this.className = this.className.replace("animate", "");
        else
            this.className = this.className + " animate";
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

Pure JS [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Marventus/g0ppcko7/).

### With jQuery:

```
function onTransitionEnd(event) {
    console.log(event);
    window.location.href = event.target.href;
}
$("a", this).on("click", function (e) {
    if ( $(this).hasClass("animate") )
        $(this).removeClass("animate");
    else
        $(this).addClass("animate");
    $("a").on("transitionend", function () {
        onTransitionEnd(e);
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

jQuery [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Marventus/2fcf2m3L/).

### With OP's Code (Pure JS):

```
function onTransitionEnd(event) {

    /* do stuff here */

    // Uncomment line below to refire the event
    // event.target.dispatchEvent(event);
}

{
    .....,
    views: { ... },
    onExit: function(e){
        someEle.addEventListener("transitionend", function() {
            // Uncomment lines below to be able refire the event on `transitionend`
            /* delete e.defaultPrevented;
            e.defaultPrevented = false; */
            onTransitionEnd(e);
        });
        someEle.classList.remove("someClass");   //CSS transition
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work with back button on navigator. State transition will still occur.